# Set cookie's secure flag in IE11 (client-side)

Tags: javascript, cookies, https, client

As seen in the screenshot, setting this in the dev console just ignores the flag.

```
document.cookie="test=that;secure"
```

Adding a domain or a path does not seems to help either. (Another SO answer was saying that made it work)

This works flawlessly in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

[image: IE11Win7]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see the point in setting the secure flag locally even if it is possible.  This cookie flag should be set by your web application or a webserver running in front of your application.

Comment: The cookie data is manage on the client-side. It can make sense to manage how this data is to be used here as well.

Comment: The secure flag exists to prevent client side access to cookies on non https connections.  If you are on an https connection already then it doesn't do anything and if you are on an http connection setting the flag is only going to remove your access to the cookie, assuming it does anything at all.

Comment: If you go sometimes on the HTTPS, sometimes on the HTTP of the same site, it may be useful to keep the cookie only to the HTTPS part. Right?